# How can I handle HttpURLConnection callback/response from the server

Tags: java, android

The below code works perfectly fine only that I have found it difficult to handle callback response and give it back to the user

```
URL url = new URL(HttpUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");           
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);               
JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("phone", "254" + phone);
jsonParam.put("loanno", loanno);
jsonParam.put("amount", amount);
jsonParam.put("memberno", sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, ""));
Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
os.flush();
os.close();
Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());
conn.disconnect();
progressDialog.dismiss();
finish();
```

Comment: what about some tutorial? https://medium.com/@lewisjkl/android-httpurlconnection-with-asynctask-tutorial-7ce5bf0245cd

Comment: You are not even reading the response.

Comment: Thanks this tutorial has help me...https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial  https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108972/greenapps I was trying to find out how to read the response